# How to create a sublist inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

I have a question on how to create a sublist in python.

I want to input 3 values and add them in a sublist with a function and call them 3 times.

But for a reason i cannot create the sublist.

I want my output to be something like this:
*[['string1','string2','string3'], [10, 20, 30], [2.7, 5.5, 12.2]]*

```
word = input("add text (end stops): ")
list=[]
while word != 'end':
    a = int(input("add int: "))
    b = float(input("add float: "))
    word = input("add text (end stops): ")

def fixlist(lst, st):
    list=[]
    for item in lst:
        list.append(lst)
        for y in item:
            list.append(st[item])
    return [lst, st]


print(fixlist(list, word))
print(fixlist(list, a))
print(fixlist(list, b))
```

This is my **output**:

```
[[], 'end']
[[], 10]
[[], 5.5]
```

Comment: Your not appending to your sublist, you first receive all the inputs, throwing away older inputs. and then build your sublists according to the last input.

Comment: do not use `list, set,dict,tuple,max,min,...` as variable names - you are shadowing the built ins that already took that name

Comment: @Dinari what do you mean by throwing away older inputs?

Comment: Your overriding the values in `a` , `b` and `word` on every iteration. if you want to store them you need to keep em in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code:

```
list=[]
```

As Patrick mentioned, do not use keywords as variable names.

```
while word != 'end':
    a = int(input("add int: "))
    b = float(input("add float: "))
    word = input("add text (end stops): ")
```

When you execute this code, you keep geting new input, but you are throwing away your old input. You need to store your older input if you wish to use it later. for example:

```
word = input("add text (end stops): ")
all_string_inputs = []
while word != 'end':
    all_string_inputs.append(word)
    word = input("add text (end stops): ")
```

In the above code i store the older inputs in the `all_string_input`  list.

If you wish to enter only 3 values, do not use a while.

```
def fixlist(lst, st):
    list=[]
    for item in lst:
        list.append(lst)
        for y in item:
            list.append(st[item])
    return [lst, st]
```

What are you intending to do here? in the above code you iterate over the items in `lst`, for which your input is an empty list. And in the end you return your input. Without changing it. Also note that `st[item]` is not defined, as `item` is not necissarly an int.

If you wish to append to an existing list inside a function, you need to use the following scheme:

```
def fixlist(lst, st):
    lst.append(st)
```

The above will modify the existing list. If you wish to create a new list, you need to return the new list:

```
def fixlist(lst, st):
    new_list = lst+[st]
    return new_list
```

The above will create a new list with `lst` and `st`, and returns it.

Try to fix your code now, if that still fails, edit the question with your attempts.

Comment: I fixed almost all my issues but the thing is my sublists are printed in different rows instead of one row.

Comment: Are you printing them with different `print` functions? if so then it adds a newline. you can use `print(<some thing>, end='')` to print without the newline.

Comment: It was a different problem, but though trial and error i fixed it. I can't thank you enough! Thanks a lot for your help and your patience!

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Please provide data!\n-----------------\n")

data = [
    [], [], []
]

while True:
    line = input("Enter: ")
    line = line.split(" ")

    if line[0].lower() == "end":
        print("\nEntering ended.\n")
        break

    data[0].append(line[0])
    data[1].append(int(line[1]))
    data[2].append(float(line[2]))

print(data)
```